# Unable to compute gradients efficiently in TF 1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, neural-network, computation

**System information**

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow):
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):  Ubuntu 18.04
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.14
- Python version: 3.7.3
- GPU model: Titan X (Pascal)
- CUDA Version: 10.1

**Problem Statement**

So, I am trying to find the gradients of outputs with respect to inputs but my decoder model is a GRU.  First, I used the code below, which works but is quite slow since my input is a 56 dimension vector but the output is of (276,77) dimensional matrix:

```
        def get_gradients(i):
            return tf.gradients(self.decoder_output[:, i], self.decoder_input)[0]

        output_dim = self.decoder_output.shape[1].value
        J = [get_gradients(i) for i in tqdm_notebook(range(output_dim))]
```

Then, I looked to change it to while loop but apparently it gave me this error which means I cant have a nested while loop in which I am calculating gradients.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Cannot use 'while_1/gradients/f_count' as input to 'while_1/gradients/f_count_1' because they are in different while loops.

while_1/gradients/f_count_1 while context: gru_3/while/while_context
while_1/gradients/f_count while context: while_1/while_context
```

- Is there way around this? Isn't there any other way in tensorflow to compute gradients?
- or if there is any other way to make the computation faster?